# XSLT/XPath function month-from-dateTime(datetime) not working as expected

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0, saxon

In my XSLT stylesheet I extract the value of the current month using a `month-from-dateTime` like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" ...>
...
<xsl:value-of select="fn:month-from-dateTime(fn:current-dateTime())" />
```

This returns `3` (for march) but according to this [XSL reference](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp#datetime) I would expect it to return the value with a leading zero: `03`. Anything I am missing? I use `TransformerFactory` from Saxon9HE.

Comment: Long time ago we had even a "canonical" link to advise against the use of w3schools as reference.

Comment: It actually returns an integer, not a string, which xsl:value-of then converts to a text node using the standard integer-to-string conversion rules, which of course do not include adding leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-month-from-dateTime)

> fn:month-from-dateTime(xs:dateTime("1999-05-31T13:20:00-05:00"))
>   returns 5.

So my expectation was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the return as:

```
fn:format-number(fn:month-from-dateTime(xs:dateTime("1999-05-31T13:20:00-05:00")), '00')
```

it will return 05